# Javascript Object Event Handler Scope, best practice(s)?

Tags: javascript, scope, event-handling, dom-events

I'm currently writing a Javascript module that basically provides a form to submit.

While writing it, I ran into what seems to be a classic scope problem.

I want the `submit()` method to make an AJAX call and use an object method to handle the success and fail of the call. Since `submit()` is an event handler, `this` is no longer set to the `flagBox` object. Thus, I no longer have access to `flagBox.showSuccess()` or `flagBox.showFail()`.

At first, I was looking for a way to set an object-wide self reference, so that I could call something like `self.showSuccess()`.

For now, I'm using `jQuery.proxy()` to set the context of the handler.

I also thought about implementing a pub/sub pattern or by attaching the method to `event.data`.

I'm curious what other solutions are out there, and if there are any 'best practices' that I haven't found.

```
(function( $ ) {

    var FlagBox = function() {};
    FlagBox.prototype = {

        constructor: FlagBox,

        init: function() {
            $('.flag-content-box')
                .on('submit', $.proxy(this.submit, this));
        },

        ...

        showSuccess: function() {
            console.log('success');
        },

        showFail: function() {
            console.log('fail');
        },

        submit: function(event) {
            event.preventDefault();

            var that = this;
                formData = $(event.target).serializeObject();

            $.ajax({
                type:"POST",
                url: '/flag/add.json',
                data: formData,
                success : function(data) {
                    that.showSuccess();
                },
                error : function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                    showFail();
                }
            });
        }
    };

    var flagBox = new FlagBox();
    flagBox.init();

})(jQuery);
```

Comment: Using `var that = this;` is a common (and I think appropriate) pattern.

Answer (score 0):

You can bind the success/failure methods to your object like this. This way always the success/failure methods will be called with your object's context.

```
(function( $ ) {

    var FlagBox = function() {};
    FlagBox.prototype = {

        constructor: FlagBox,

        init: function() {
            $('.flag-content-box')
                .on('submit', $.proxy(this.submit, this));
        },

        ...

        showSuccess: function() {
            console.log('success');
        },

        showFail: function() {
            console.log('fail');
        },

        submit: function(event) {
            event.preventDefault();

            var that = this;
                formData = $(event.target).serializeObject();

            var successFn = (function(obj){
                return function(){
                    return obj.showSuccess.apply(obj, arguments)
                }
            })(this);  

            var failureFn = (function(obj){
                return function(){
                    return obj.showFailure.apply(obj, arguments);
                }
            })(this);  

            $.ajax({
                type:"POST",
                url: '/flag/add.json',
                data: formData,
                success : successFn,
                error : failureFn
            });
        }
    };

    var flagBox = new FlagBox();
    flagBox.init();

})(jQuery);
```

Comment: It seems simpler to use [bind](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind): `var successFn = this.showSuccess.bind(this);`.

Comment: The `bind` function is a recent addition to JS, 5th edition and may not be present in all browsers.

Comment: Isn't `this` passed to `successFn()` the context of the event handler and not the object? Or do you mean to pass `that`?

Comment: Whatever the event handler passes to `successFn` it will eventually use the object to call the success/Failure methods.